# React Native. Проблема с компиляцией

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь разобраться в React Native под Android.
Удалось все настроить, запустить. App.js, который генерируется при создании проекта - работает. Сообщение выводится на экран телефона через Expo.

```
    import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Привет!</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Но, если я пытаюсь скомпилировать код из официальной документации 
http://reactnativedocs.ru/docs/tutorial.html

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

То появляется ошибка

> > 12:05:27: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> >     components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your
> >     component from the file it's defined in.
>
> Check the render method of `AwakeInDevApp`.
>       in AwakeInDevApp (at registerRootComponent.js:33)
>       in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:113)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:100)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:113)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:121)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Так это же не ошибка, а Warning.

Comment: Но приложение не запускается тем не менее. Еще валятся ошибки на экране устройства.

Answer (score 0):

А чем вам не нравится первый пример? Используйте его. Скорее всего проблема в `AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);`